# How to Have a Single Query to LEFT JOIN with IF condition Like This?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table, named `profit_loss` :

```
+--------------------+------------+----------+-------------+------------------+
| timestamp          | fee        | fee_unit | profit_loss | profit_loss_unit |
+--------------------+------------+----------+-------------+------------------+
| lm83-1526098952020 | 0.00750007 | BNB      |  0.09672160 | USDT             |
| lm83-1526098952020 | 0.00750007 | BNB      |  0.00000000 | BNB              |
| lm83-1526098952020 | 0.00750007 | BNB      |  0.00000050 | BTC              |
+--------------------+------------+----------+-------------+------------------+
```

and also have this, named `trading_price` :

```
+--------------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| timestamp          | pair_name | bid_price     | ask_price     |
+--------------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| lm83-1526098952020 | NEOUSDT   |   63.14000000 |   63.20000000 |
| lm83-1526098952020 | NEOBTC    |    0.00749700 |    0.00749900 |
| lm83-1526098952020 | NEOETH    |    0.09287900 |    0.09319500 |
| lm83-1526098952020 | NEOBNB    |    4.95100000 |    4.96700000 |
| lm83-1526098952020 | BNBUSDT   |   12.73850000 |   12.74580000 |
| lm83-1526098952020 | BNBBTC    |    0.00151130 |    0.00151190 |
| lm83-1526098952020 | BNBETH    |    0.01873500 |    0.01876000 |
| lm83-1526098952020 | LTCBNB    |   10.73000000 |   10.77000000 |
| lm83-1526098952020 | BCCBNB    |  107.73000000 |  108.37000000 |
| lm83-1526098952020 | LTCUSDT   |  136.80000000 |  137.14000000 |
| lm83-1526098952020 | LTCBTC    |    0.01625800 |    0.01627000 |
| lm83-1526098952020 | LTCETH    |    0.20172000 |    0.01627000 |
| lm83-1526098952020 | BCCUSDT   | 1372.01000000 | 1374.11000000 |
| lm83-1526098952020 | BCCBTC    |    0.16314900 |    0.16315100 |
| lm83-1526098952020 | BCCETH    |    2.02004000 |    2.02785000 |
| lm83-1526098952020 | BTCUSDT   | 8412.13000000 | 8412.14000000 |
| lm83-1526098952020 | ETHUSDT   |  677.88000000 |  678.55000000 |
| lm83-1526098952020 | ETHBTC    |    0.08055000 |    0.08060500 |
+--------------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

how to `LEFT JOIN` those tables so that the result will be like this?

```
+--------------------+------------+----------+-------------+------------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| timestamp          | fee        | fee_unit | profit_loss | profit_loss_unit | pair_name | bid_price     | ask_price     |
+--------------------+------------+----------+-------------+------------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| lm83-1526098952020 | 0.00750007 | BNB      |  0.09672160 | USDT             | BNBUSDT   |   12.73850000 |   12.74580000 |
| lm83-1526098952020 | 0.00750007 | BNB      |  0.00000000 | BNB              | BNBBNB    |    1          |    1          |
| lm83-1526098952020 | 0.00750007 | BNB      |  0.00000050 | BTC              | BNBBTC    |    0.00151130 |    0.00151190 |
+--------------------+------------+----------+-------------+------------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

please keep in mind that I only need `trading_price.pair_name` based on `profit_loss.fee_unit` and `profit_loss.profit_loss_unit` combined.

but with if condition like this :

`profit_loss.fee_unit` and `profit_loss.profit_loss_unit`

combined is not exist, then try the opposite way :

`profit_loss.profit_loss_unit` and `profit_loss.fee_unit`

how to have a single query to `LEFT JOIN` with `IF` condition like this?

Comment: What's your key for make a relation between those tables?

Comment: @Ulises : timestamp column.

Comment: Why are pairnames like for example `NEOUSDT` not in expected resultset?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense as the `timestamp` column isn't unique in either table - if that's what the relationship actually is - so you've got a many-to-many relationship with no bridging table.

Comment: @RaymondNijland : I only need pair relates to `profit_loss.fee_unit` and `profit_loss.profit_loss_unit ` on each timestamp.

Comment: So if is on the same table why the importance of Left Join you wanna use an operator for columns that are on the same table.

Comment: @Ulises : I'm sorry. I don't get it... what do you mean by same table? it's not same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use two left join operations, to attempt to get both of the matching rows, and then use expressions in the SELECT list that test whether a matching row was found.

```
SELECT p.timestamp
     , ...

     , CASE WHEN t.timestamp IS NOT NULL
        THEN t.pairname
        ELSE r.pairname
       END AS pairname

     , CASE WHEN t.timestamp IS NOT NULL
        THEN t.bidprice
        ELSE r.bidprice
       END AS bidprice

     , IF(t.timestamp IS NULL, r.askprice, t.askprice)  AS askprice

  FROM profit_loss p
  LEFT
  JOIN trading_price t
    ON t.timestamp = p.timestamp 
   AND t.pairname  = CONCAT(p.fee_unit,p.profit_loss_unit)
  LEFT
  JOIN trading_price r
    ON t.timestamp IS NULL
   AND r.timestamp = p.timestamp
   AND r.pairname  = CONCAT(p.profit_loss_unit,p.fee_unit)
 WHERE ...
 ORDER BY ...
```

In the LEFT JOIN to r, the condition on `t.timestamp` will check whether we found a matching row from `t`. If we found a matching row, then this condition will evaluate to FALSE, so no rows from `r` will match. Conversely, if no matching row from `t`, then this condition will evaluate to TRUE, so we will return any matching rows from `r`.

If there are multiple rows matched in `t`, this query will return multiple copies of the row from `p`, a copy for each matching row from `t`. (If no rows matched in `t`, then same issue with `r`.)  (We mention this because don't see any guarantee that there won't be more than one matching row.)

This is an example of just one approach; there are other query patterns that will achieve an equivalent result.

---

**EDIT**

NOTES:

The query will return a row from `p` when there are no matching rows in `t` or `r`. If the requirement is that a row from `p` be returned only if a matching row is found, then we could handle that condition in a HAVING clause, immediately before the ORDER BY, a condition that tests whether a row was returned

```
 HAVING (t.pairname IS NOT NULL OR r.pairname IS NOT NULL)
```

If we have a *guarantee* that `askprice` and `bidprice` will not be NULL, then we could simplify the expressions in the SELECT list

```
     , IFNULL(t.pairname,r.pairname) AS pairname
     , IFNULL(t.bidprice,r.bidprice) AS bidprice
     , IFNULL(t.askprice,r.askprice) AS askprice
```

There's a variety of expressions we can use in the SELECT list to achieve an equivalent result.